# Binding label with conditional content?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `Label` that needs to display the number of elements in an `ObservableList`. I have the `IntegerBinding` setup, but I also need to adjust the wording of the `Label` based on how many elements are in the list.

For the MCVE below, if there is only one element in the list, it should display "The list contains 1 item."  But "item" needs to be plural if the list is empty or contains multiple items: "The list contains 3 items."

I have tried to do so using both a ternary operator and a `BooleanBinding`, but neither has any effect as the ternary expression only seems to be evaluated once. Clicking the "Add" button does not change the "items" portion of the `Label`.

---

> **THE CODE**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.IntegerBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private IntegerBinding listSize = Bindings.size(items);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Label label = new Label();

        // Bind the label to display a size-aware notification
        label.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.concat("The list contains ", listSize,
                        ((items.size() != 1) ? " items!" : " item!"))
        );

        // Button to add items
        Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction(event -> items.add("new item"));

        root.getChildren().addAll(label, button);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

Do I need to include a listener for when the size of the list changes?

Comment: What about using a custom `StringBinding()` and do the the check of the list size  inside the `computeValue()` in order to create and return the correct String?

Comment: @JKostikiadis - I'll give that a shot right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick solution using a custom StringBinding()

```
// Bind the label to display a size-aware notification
label.textProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
    { bind(listSize); }

    @Override
    protected String computeValue() {
        return "The list contains " + listSize.get() + ((items.size() != 1) ? " items!" : " item!");
    }

});
```

In the code above you will listen to the listSize for changes and then you will create the new String inside the computeValue().

Answer (score 4):

This is the shorter equivalent:

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
                              () -> "The list contains " + listSize.get() + ((itemSize.get() != 1) ? " items!" : " item!",
                              listSize
                          ));
```

Or another alternative:

```
label.textProperty.bind(Bindings
                           .when(listSize.isEqualTo(1))
                           .then("The list contains 1 item!")
                           .otherwise(
                               Bindings.concat("The list contains " + listSize + " items!")
                           )
                       );
```